# Regex substitution that returns a trimmed version of the input?

Tags: python

I am dealing with a variety of "five and two" strings that refer to an individual. The strings have the first five letters of an individual's last name, and then the first two letters of the individual's first name. Each string concludes with a two digit numeral that acts as a "tiebreaker" if more than two individuals have the same "five and two." The numerals are to be considered strings. In the event of an individual who possesses a last name shorter than five letters, the entire last name is included in the string with no extra characters to fill in the gap.

Examples:

```
adamsjo02
allenje01
alstoga01
ariasge01
aucoide01
ayraujo01
belkti01 #This individual has a last name with only four letters
```

I wish to convert each of these strings into a "four and one" string that has a three digit numeral. The result of the above examples after being converted should look like this:

```
adamj002
allej001
alstg001
ariag001
aucod001
ayraj001
belkt001
```

I am using python throughout my project. I suspect that a regex substitution would be the best course of action to achieve what I need. I have little experience with regexes, and have come up with this thus far to detect the regex:

```
re.compile(r'(/w){2,5}(/w/w)(/w/w)')
```

While this does not work for me, it does lay out that I perceive there to be three groupings in each string. The last name portion, the first name portion, and the numerals (to be treated as strings). Each of those groupings ought to be undergoing a change, with exception to any individual that may have a last name of four or fewer letters.

Comment: did you mean to use `\w`? backslash is the escape character

Answer (score 0):

You can do with a proper escape character `\` and [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```py
import re

text = '''adamsjo02
allenje01
alstoga01
ariasge01
aucoide01
ayraujo01
belkti01
maja01'''


p = re.compile(r"(\w{2,5})(\w{2})(\d{2})")
output = [f"{m.group(1):_<4.4}{m.group(2):1.1}{m.group(3):0>3}" for m in map(p.search, text.splitlines())]

print(output)
# ['adamj002', 'allej001', 'alstg001', 'ariag001', 'aucod001', 'ayraj001', 'belkt001', 'ma__j001']
```

Comment: Thanks for this responce, May you note that OP require "**four and one**" string, that means one char for the first name. i.e, **adamjo002** will be **adamj002**

Comment: @AziMez Oh thank you for reminding me of that! I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since you have a very specific format, I'd say regex is not necessary, though it does the job. I'm proposing, then, an alternate solution without using it.

```py
def to_four_one(code: str) -> str:
    last, first, number = code[:-4][:4], code[-4:-2], int(code[-2:])
    return f"{last}{first[-2]}{number:03}"
```

It's a simple function that rearranges the elements in the string. It simply gets the last name, first name and number as different elements, and rewrites them as the new format asks (clipping last names for len == 4, and first names for len == 1, besides formatting the number as 3 digit).

Usage below. I added two more names with even less characters to show it doesn't break in those cases.

```py
codes = [
    "adamsjo02",
    "allenje01",
    "alstoga01",
    "ariasge01",
    "aucoide01",
    "ayraujo01",
    "belkti01",
    "jorma03",
    "baka02"]

[print(to_four_one(code)) for code in codes]

>>>adamj002
allej001
alstg001
ariag001
aucod001
ayraj001
belkt001
jorm003
bak002
```